# Ugly xml output

Tags: xml, haskell, haxml

I'm using HaXml to transform a XML file and it's all quite working nicely. However the output HaXml generates looks really ugly, mainly because it inserts a linebreak at almost every closing bracket.
Here's some code that generates a xml:

```
writeFile outPath (show . PP.content . head $ test (docContent (posInNewCxt "" Nothing) (xmlParse "" "")))

test = 
    mkElemAttr "test" [("a", literal "1"), ("b", literal "2")]
        [
            mkElem "nested" []
        ]
```

and here's the output it generates:

```
<test a="1" b="2"
  ><nested/></test>
```

Of course it is worse with more elements.

I know that HaXml uses Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ for rendering, but using different [styles](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pretty/1.0.1.2/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-HughesPJ.html#8)
 didn't change much.

So, is there a way to change the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing you call to `show` with [`Text.PrettyPrint.renderStyle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pretty/1.0.1.2/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-HughesPJ.html#v%3arenderStyle) you can get a few different behaviors:

```
import Text.XML.HaXml
import Text.XML.HaXml.Util
import Text.XML.HaXml.Posn
import qualified Text.XML.HaXml.Pretty as PP
import Text.PrettyPrint

main = writeFile "/tmp/x.xml" (renderStyle s . PP.content 
                                             . head $
               test (docContent (posInNewCxt "" Nothing) (xmlParse "" "")))
    where
        s = style { mode = LeftMode, lineLength = 2 }

test = 
    mkElemAttr "test" [("a", literal "1"), ("b", literal "2")]
        [
            mkElem "nested" []
        ]
```

Experimenting with different out-of-the-box styles:

*Default style*

```
<test a="1" b="2"
  ><nested/></test>
```

*style { mode = OneLineMode }*

```
<test a="1" b="2" ><nested/></test>
```

*style { mode = LeftMode, lineLength = 2 }*

```
<test a="1"
b="2"
><nested/></test>
```

So you can certainly do a few different things.

If you don't like any of these, you can write a custom processors, using [`fullRender`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pretty/1.0.1.2/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-HughesPJ.html#v%3afullRender):

```
fullRender
    :: Mode                     -- Rendering mode
    -> Int                      -- Line length
    -> Float                    -- Ribbons per line
    -> (TextDetails -> a -> a)  -- What to do with text
    -> a                        -- What to do at the end
    -> Doc                      -- The document
    -> a                        -- Result
```

where your custom behavior can be programmed into the `TextDetails` function.

Comment: Mh, I guess I'll have to write my own fullRender, or simply live with the result. Maybe I'll try to copy the existing default style and remove the linebreak.